# without using explicite coordinates - graph with nodes aligned above

Tags: graphs

I want to draw a structure as shown in the picture 
[image: lattice]

so that the knots 3 and 2 are on the top left and top right of 1. And 4 should be in the middle of 3 and 2 in the level on top of them and so on. I tried hard in the last few hours but the best result I got is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \graph [grow up=10mm, branch right=10mm] {0--1--{3--4,2--{4,5}--6}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image: TeX-Output]

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

EDIT: I'm looking for code that **doesn't use explicit coordinates** because I have to draw a lot more (and bigger) structures.

Answer (score 2):

By adding specific `x`-coordinates for the nodes 3 and 5 you get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \graph [grow up=10mm, branch right=10mm] {0--1--{3[x=-1]--4,2--{4,5[x=1]}--6}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility to get this result without using coordinates? (\graph [more options here...] ) I have a lot of similar bigger graphs to draw...

Comment: @Chipsy Don't know, I'm afraid. I just browsed the manual until I found something that might work, I never draw these kinds of things myself.